# How can i find the expected value?

Tags: probability, expected-value

The textbook was published in a circulation of 100000 copies. The probability that the textbook is not properly stitched is 0.0001. Compile a series of the distribution of the number of textbooks that are not properly stitched. Find E(ξ) of this random variable.

My solution. But can i find E(ξ) faster?

[image]

Comment: If there are $N$ trials and the success probability is $p$ then the expected number of successes is $Np$.

Comment: @lulu But as i know formula for expected value is 
$E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^nx_{i}p_{i}$

Comment: But you already used the mean in computing $\lambda =Np=10$. A least, I assume you were trying to write out the Poisson approximation to the distribution (what you wrote isn't correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The *exact* distribution of the number of improperly stitched textbooks is binomial:
  \begin{align}
  P_{100000}(k)&={100000 \choose k}0.0001^k\,0.9999^{100000-k}\\
  &={N\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}\,
  \end{align}
  where $\ N=100000\ $ and $\ p=0.0001\ $.  For this distribution, $\ E(\xi)=Np=10\ $, as [lulu's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) comment notes.
- The distribution you've used is the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), which can be a good *approximation* to the binomial distribution when $\ N\ $ is large and $\ p\ $ or $\ 1-p\ $ is small.  Since that *is* the case here, using the Poisson approximation is reasonable:
  $$
  P_{100000}(k)\approx\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\ ,
  $$
  but $\ \lambda $ here must be the expected number, $\ Np\ $ ($\ =10\ $ for your example), so it would appear that you already knew this???
- You have some typos in your expression for $\ P_{100000}(k)\ $. It should be
  $$
  P_{100000}(k)\approx\frac{\lambda^{\color{red} k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}=\frac{10^{\color{red} k}}{10!}e^{-10}\ ,
  $$
  and I have no idea what $\ k=\overline{0,100000}\ $ means.
- In your formula for $\ E(\xi)\ $ you need to have $\ x_k=k\ $. That is, $\ E(\xi)=\sum_\limits{k=1}^{100000}kP_{100000}(k)\ $.  For the binomial distribution this becomes
  \begin{align}
  E(\xi)&= \sum_{k=1}^N k {N\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}\\
  &=Np \sum_{k=1}^N {N-1\choose k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{(N-1)-(k-1)}\\
  &=Np \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} {N-1\choose j}p^j(1-p)^{(N-1)-j}\\
  &=Np\ ,
  \end{align}
  and for the Poisson distribution, it is
  \begin{align}
  E(\xi)&= \sum_{k=1}^Nk \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\\
  &=\lambda e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\\
  &= \lambda e^{-\lambda} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}\\\\
  &\approx\lambda
  \end{align}
  when $\ N\ $ is very large.

Comment: Thank you very much. k=1,10 - it means that k can be from 1 to 10